# Query using Union, to fetch data from first table and use it in other part of UNION query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to write a query for following scenario:

```
Select Time, Column A, Column B
From Table A
UNION 
Select Time, Column X, Column Y
From Table B
```

Data will come as below from both queries:
from Table A-

```
Time   |Column A |Column B|
Oct-17 | 20      | 10     |
Nov-17 | 25      | 15     |
Dec-17 | 40      | 30     |
```

from Table B

```
Time  |Column X  |Column Y|
Jan-18| 30       |15      |
```

Expected Output:

```
Time   | Column A | Column B|
Oct-17 | 20       | 10      |
Nov-17 | 25       | 15      |
Dec-17 | 40       | 30      |
Jan-18 | 30/40    |15       |
```

While we do the union, I need Dec-17 Column A value (Table A) to calculate Column X of Jan-18 (Table B). I don't want to join Table A in second part of query because I have only given dummy data here, actual query is real big and already has lots of tables joining.
I tried using left join also but it is not working. Can anyone please help what to be done in such scenarios.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: What if u have 2 rows in table B, does second row also computed as value/40 ?

Comment: Yes, second row will also be value/40

Comment: so in this case all rows from second table will attain value/lastrow of first table

Comment: Yes, this is my requirement

Comment: If u have any ID column in your table, you can select max(row) from first table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it using temp table and the query is taking less time so thought of sharing it. Other answers were really helpful for me to get this solution.

```
Create Table ##TempTable
(
 Time varchar,
 [Column A] float,
 [Column B] float,
 first int,
 ID varchar
)
INSERT INTO ##TempTable
Select Time, [Column A], [Column B], first,ID
from
(
 Select Time, [Column A], [Column B],1 as first,ID
 From tablea
 union all
 Select Time, [Column X], [Column Y],2 as second,ID
 From tableb
)A

Select Time, 
CASE WHEN A.first = 1 THEN A.[Column A]  
ELSE (B.[Column A]/A.[Column A]) END [Column A],
[Column B]
From ##TempTable A
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ##TempTable WHERE first=1 ORDER BY ID DESC  ) B
ON A.ID >= B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *CTE* to calculate the values from *tablea* with value of *tableb*

```
with cte as
(
    Select Time, [Column A], [Column B],1 as first
    From tablea
    union all
    Select Time, [Column X], [Column Y],2 as second
    From tableb
)

select time,
       case when first = 1 then cast([Column A] as varchar) else concat([Column A] ,  '/' ,
           (select top 1 [Column A] from cte where first = 1 order by time))
       end [Column A], [Column B] 
from cte c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and some conditional logic functions, assuming that `time` is stored in a reasonable format:

```
select time,
       (case when lag(year(time)) over (order by time) <> year(time) over (order by time)
             then [Column A] + '/' + lag([Column A]) over (order by time)
             else [Column A]
        end) as [Column A],
       [Column B]
from ((Select Time, [Column A], [Column B]
       From tablea
      ) union all
      (Select Time, [Column X], [Column Y]
       From tableb
      )
     ) a;
```

This assumes that the logic for the pairing is because the row is the first in the year.  Of course, you can just a simpler expression such as looking at the exact time.